# The type or namespace name `SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace `UnityEditor.Experimental'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got this error after importing a framework into my project:

> The type or namespace name `SceneManagement' does not exist in the namespace` UnityEditor.Experimental'. Are you missing an assembly
> reference?

I'm using Unity 2018.2.18f.

What should I do to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

SceneManegement namespace is belongs to `UnityEngine.SceneManagement` , i think if you add this namespace your problem will be solved.

Comment: I tried adding UnityEngine.SceneManagement, but I got another errors when deleting UnityEditor.Experimental.SceneManagement!

Comment: Did you get this error when you're trying to get build or what? Because sometimes when you trying to build unity can be add some libraries which will cause problem. If you can give detail maybe i can help you.

Comment: it didn't allow the playmode to run, so of course it will not allow the build also

Comment: I mean not play, to get executable build of your game. And again I repeat, it is not possible to solve the problem without providing really useful details. I can only suggest that you can create a new script and try running your code there.